# Is there any way to make the libraries from python to work?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I have been struggling for several hours to import keras and tensorflow, but I am unable to import them.

```
 import os
import random
import sys


# Package
import glob
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import IPython.display as ipd
import librosa
import librosa.display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

Also, when I try to import something, I am unable to do that. Could someone help me out ?
Thank you !

These are the errors I got:

```
Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vlad/speech_recognition/emotionrecognition.py", line 8, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Please add that to your question.

Comment: The question is completely unanswerable without error messages and actual details

Comment: Did you actually install tensorflow? If so, how exactly?

Comment: Have you installed tensorflow package. Try `pip install tensorflow` or `pip install tensorflow-gpu` (if you are using GPU).

Comment: Need to install Tensorflow first, `pip install tensorflow`. Follow the instructions mentioned on Tensorflow installation guide https://www.tensorflow.org/install.